# How to properly use pattern matching in java

Tags: java, regex

**Update:**

I've found the solution thanks to @dasblinkenlight and all other good samaritans.
The working code is here for any of you with similar question:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\s)([-+*%/^])(\\s)(\\d+)");
Matcher matchOp1 = pattern.matcher(text);
matchOp1.find();
System.out.println(matchOp1.group(1));
```

This will only print the first group.

**Original Question:**

First and foremost, I cannot use any if statements, therefore I must catch and handle exceptions only.

Assume i have a string which contains "10 + 20".

I have the following regex: "(\d\+)(\s)([\+\-\*\%\^])(\s)([\d\+)".
This regex is intended to match (integer of any length)(space)(an operator)(space)(integer of any length)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\+)(\\s)([\\+\\-\\*\\%\\^])(\\s)([\\d\\+)");
Matcher matchOp1 = pattern.matcher("1 + 1");
System.out.println(matchOp1.group(1));
```

I want this to print "10" only if there's a match, but this throws PatternSyntaxException. Can anyone give me some insight please?

Thank you!

Comment: A quick way to test the regex sanity is to test that with some online tools like : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `[` in your pattern, and you escaped pluses where you shouldn't have:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\+)(\\s)([\\+\\-\\*\\%\\^])(\\s)([\\d\\+)");
//                                     ^^                                ^   ^^
```

Removing these will fix the problem.

Note that escaping meta-characters inside character class `[...]` is not necessary: just be careful to move `-` to one of the ends, and place `^` in any position other than first:

```
"(\\d+)(\\s)([-+*%/^])(\\s)(\\d+)"
```

Note that with all these unnecessary backslashes you forgot the division sign.

Comment: Thanks for the responds, but this throws PatternSyntaxException

Comment: this throws a no match found exception :(

Comment: @noobcoder That's because you never called `find()` on `matchOp1` ([demo](http://ideone.com/5CfIWl)).

Answer (score 2):

You've some issues in your regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\+)(\\s)([\\+\\-\\*\\%\\^])(\\s)([\\d\\+)");
                                         ^                               ^     ^
```

1. You havent closed your square brackets
2. You should not escape `+` as it is there to indicate more than 1 digit, NOT literally `+`.
3. It will throw `IllegalStateException` so you have to place `if(matchOp1.find())` before capturing group.

Instead, it should be like:

```
(\d+)(\s)([\+\-\*\%\^])(\s)(\d+)
```

and while using in code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\s)([\\+\\-\\*\\%\\^])(\\s)(\\d+)");
Matcher matchOp1 = pattern.matcher("1 + 1");
if(matchOp1.find())
    System.out.println(matchOp1.group(1));
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MLXoU9/1)